# Как в изменить width visualElement в процентах?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть категория с картами, которую по нажатия на кнопку мы должны либо развернуть, либо, наоборот, уменьшить до начальных размеров. Я нашел способ, как это сделать, но, как я понимаю, это далеко не в процентах.

```
VisualElement cat1;
Button okButton;
void Start()
{
    var uiDocument = GetComponent<UIDocument>();
    okButton = uiDocument.rootVisualElement.Q<Button>("Up1");
    cat1 = uiDocument.rootVisualElement.Q<VisualElement>("Category1");
    okButton.clicked += ClickMessage;
}

void ClickMessage()
{
    Debug.Log("hello");
    cat1.style.width = 100;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В <kbd>UXML</kbd> файле пишется просто `width = 10%`.

---

`visual.style.width` можно присвоить цифровое значение, но как и другие размерности стиля, это не `float`, а [StyleLength](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UIElements.StyleLength.html). Для получения значения прийдется писать так:

```
float width = visual.style.width.value;
```

---

Кроме `value`, у [StyleLength](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UIElements.StyleLength.html) есть `keyword`([StyleKeyword](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UIElements.StyleKeyword.html)). Можем увидеть знакомые по интерфейсу билдера <kbd>Auto</kbd> и <kbd>Initial</kbd>, а так-же <kbd>None</kbd>, <kbd>Null</kbd> и <kbd>Undefined</kbd>.

---

Если попробывать посмотреть какое значение стоит у элемента, указанного в редакторе с процентами:

```
Debug.Log(visual.style.width.value + " " + visual.style.width.keyword);
```

Результат все время будет один и тот-же с вообще всеми размерностями, для всех элементов документа в принцепе: `0 Null`.

---

Проще говоря никак.

`UI Toolkit` в целом сырая вещь. Ситуаций: "*можно в редакторе но не возможно через код*", довольно много. Что бы реализовать некоторые вещи, нужно написать в десять раз больше кода, чем в классическом `uGUI`. Зачем этим пользоваться? Не знаю!